# Change \pgfplotstabletypeset font size

Tags: fontsize, pgfplotstable

I have a table with strings and fixed numbers. I need to set `\footnotesize` only to typeset it using `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

How can I change font size ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `font=\footnotesize` as an option to `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
dof error1 
4 2.5e-01 
16 6.25e-02 
64  1.5625e-02 
}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset\loadedtable
\hspace{2cm}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[font=\footnotesize]\loadedtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to change the font (shape or size) only for col names? I tried `every head row/.style={font=\itshape}` but no success.

Comment: @Sigur https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312666/586

Comment: Ow, thanks so much. I tried to search for but didn't find.

Answer (score 6):

You can just enclose your `\pgfplotstabletypeset` command in  `{\footnotesize...}` to keep the change local:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{
A B
1 2
}
{\footnotesize
\pgfplotstabletypeset{
A B
1 2
}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotesize` is *not* a command with arguments, but rather a declaration.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, moved the `{`

Comment: I moved it also in the example code