# pgfplotstable: How to replace multirowed headers with a single header spanning their columns

Tags: pgfplotstable, multirow, multicolumn

In this MWE, I used `multirow` package to make the column header span two rows, however, I would like to combine both `col1`([index]1) and `col2`([index]2) multiorwed headers to be, for example, `One Column` without deteriorating the other headers style.

```
% arara: indent: { overwrite : yes}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
radius,parameter,cubic,revised,quartic
h=1 ,13 ,34 ,5  ,9
    ,2  ,6  ,10 ,234
h=2 ,3  ,7  ,11 ,87
    ,4  ,8  ,12 ,16%
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,multirow,array,siunitx}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every col no 0/.style={column name=\multirow{2}{*}{radius},
        assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
            \else
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                    {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
                \else
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    },
    every col no 1/.style={column name=\multirow{2}{*}{col1},string type,column type=c},
    every col no 2/.style={column name=\multirow{2}{*}{col2}},
    every col no 3/.style={column name=Revised},
    every col no 4/.style={column name=\multirow{2}{*}{Quartic}},
    % use \booktabs as well (compare examples above):
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row/.add={%
            \arraybackslash
            & & & Super  & \\
            \midrule
            }{}
    },
    %
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every row no 1/.style={after row=\midrule},
    col sep=comma%
]{sample.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a workaround without `multirow`, first wipe `column name` for all header columns then add them like this

```
 every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule
      radius  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{one column}& \parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering Revised\\Super} & Quartic \\[-\normalbaselineskip]},
        after row=\midrule
                        }
```

**Code**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
radius,parameter,cubic,revised,quartic
h=1 ,13 ,34 ,5  ,9
    ,2  ,6  ,10 ,234
h=2 ,3  ,7  ,11 ,87
    ,4  ,8  ,12 ,16%
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,multirow,array,siunitx}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every col no 0/.style={column name=,
        assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
            \else
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                    {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
                \else
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    },
    every col no 1/.style={column name=\hbox to 6mm{},string type,column type=c},
    every col no 2/.style={column name=},
    every col no 3/.style={column name=},
    every col no 4/.style={column name=},
    % use \booktabs as well (compare examples above):
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule
      radius  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{one column}& {\parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering Revised\\Super}} & Quartic \\[-\normalbaselineskip]},
        after row=\midrule
             },
    %
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every row no 1/.style={after row=\midrule},
    col sep=comma%
]{sample.csv}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

To center  head text  with the other column contents you can create box which store head text then add a fraction of its width to `column name`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
radius,parameter,cubic,revised,quartic
h=1 ,13 ,34 ,5  ,9
    ,2  ,6  ,10 ,234
h=2 ,3  ,7  ,11 ,87
    ,4  ,8  ,12 ,16%
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,multirow,array,siunitx}


\newbox{\tbox}
\def\instext#1{\global\setbox\tbox=\hbox{#1}\copy\tbox}
\def\inswidth{\hspace*{0.4\wd\tbox}}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every col no 0/.style={column name=,
        assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
            \else
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
                    {\multirow{2}{*}{##1}}%
                \else
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    },
    % use \booktabs as well (compare examples above):
    every head row/.style={
        before row={ \toprule  
      radius  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\instext{column with very long head}}& {\parbox[c]{2cm}{\centering Revised\\Super}} & Quartic \\[-\normalbaselineskip]},
        after row=\midrule
             },
    every col no 1/.style={column name={\inswidth},string type,column type=c},
    every col no 2/.style={column name=},
    every col no 3/.style={column name=},
    every col no 4/.style={column name=},         
    %
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every row no 1/.style={after row=\midrule},
    col sep=comma%
]{sample.csv}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Your solution is really nice, but how can the header `one column` be centered like the others? It seems to be raggedright.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Your help is appreciated. I don't understand why the multicolumn centering fails to do its job. I wish the centering is done automatically not manually.

Comment: Answer updated with trick to center multicolumn header @DiaaAbidou

Comment: if you don't mind, can I understand the meaning of `0.4` in the second definition line?